# Не работает запрос на некоторых устройствах

Tags: reactjs, веб-программирование

Хочу спарсить ссылку, на некоторых устройствах он работает, на некоторых я получаю в консоль undefined. Как такое решить?

Код:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios.get(getGet('url')).then(r => {
        const html = r.data;
        console.log(html)

        const $ = cheerio.load(html)

        let files = JSON.parse($('#downloads').val())[0];

        console.log(files)
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])
```

Вот так выглядит консоль на Линуксе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так на маке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Про кэш не пишите, я не на столько тупой

Comment: А что есть во вкладке network и одинаковые ли браузеры? Этот же код из брвезура запускается? И что будет, если url, который парсится, подставить в адресную строку? Так же важно - само приложени тянется с одного хостинга или запускается каждое локально

Comment: все одинаковое. У меня сайт лежит на хосте, но на разных устройствах он работает вообще по другому. Бразуеры хром там и там. Такое чувство, что устройство отслеживает парсинг и блокает. На устройстве которое выдает undefined в network 307, 200 коды

Comment: Я такое мля впервые вообще вижу.

Comment: url если подставить в адресную строку, получим 404 ошибку, тк этот url для iframe, это videoplayer. К тому же, это никак не поможет, тк он работает на некоторых устройствах

Comment: Какой бы не был url, 404 отдавать не должен.

Comment: Свад, иди изучи для начала основы, а после отвечай на вопросы